# What does hardhat "deployed()" do?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

I have the below code

```
 const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
        "SimpleStorage"
    )
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    await simpleStorage.deployed()
    await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)
```

I understand that hardhat's getContractFactory is automatically supplied the abi, binary and specified private key for signing transactions. After this is done I am assuming that SimpleStorageFactory.deploy() is the same as in ethers and deploys the contract to the blockchain, and then I am waiting 6 network confirmations. However, I am confused why hardhat has await simpleStorage.deployed() and what this does?

I have tried reading the documentation on hardhat but have not found an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `await simpleStorage.deployed()` line of code is waiting for the `SimpleStorage` contract to be deployed to the Ethereum network. When a contract is deployed, it is uploaded to the network and made available for interaction.

The `deployed()` method is a Promise that returns a `ContractReceipt` object, which contains information about the deployment transaction, such as the transaction hash, block number, and contract address.

This method is useful because it allows you to ensure that the contract has been deployed and is available for interaction before you try to call any of its methods or access its state. Without this line, the rest of the code might execute before the contract is fully deployed, which could result in errors.

The `await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)` line of code is waiting for the deployment transaction to be included in six blocks on the Ethereum blockchain. This is done to ensure that the transaction has sufficient confirmations, which helps to ensure the transaction will not be reversed.

Comment: So isn't await simpleStorage.deployed() technically the same as await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait()? Waiting for 1 network confirmation?

Comment: Soft of...  deployed() helps us to ensure that our contract is properly deployed and is now ready to interact with further in our script. .deploy() handles the actual deployment whereas .deployed() will wait for block confirmations too by calling deployTransaction.wait() and can also logs error if contract is not deployed.  The .deployTransaction only exists on transactions which we deployed by a ContractFactory during this execution.

Comment: (continued) 
The .deployed() method will use the .deployTransaction if it is present (i.e. was deployed by a ContractFactrory during this execution), otherwise it will use provider.getCode to ensure there is a contract deployed at this address, which means it can be used in another process or otherwise orthogonally to a ContractFactory. This does not verify the bytecode is the correct contract (as it doesn't even know what the correct bytecode is).

So, the .deployed() will make sure there is a contract deployed at contract.address.

Comment: simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6) no longer works try 
tx = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploymentTransaction()
    await tx.wait(6)

Comment: The above comment by @Akashgreninja is valid only if you are updating to latest version of Hardhat which is trying to migrate to Ethers v6. If your Hardhat distribution uses Ethers v5.x then `deployTransaction().wait(6)` works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This hardhat plugin adds a mechanism to deploy contracts to any network, keeping track of them and replicating the same environment for testing.